# Strategy pattern using an abstract class and an interface

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, interface

I have implemented some sort of the strategy pattern using an abstract class and an interface:

```
public interface ICombination
{
    void Check(int[] hand, UsersProperties user);
    void UpdateHand(UsersProperties user, int combinationType, int powerType);
}

public abstract class ICombinationAnalyzer : CardVariables, ICombination
{
    public abstract void Check(int[] hand, UsersProperties user);

    public void UpdateHand(UsersProperties user, int combinationType, int powerType)
    {
        user.Type = combinationType;
        user.Power = powerType + user.Type*100;
        MainPoker.Win.Add(new Hand {Power = user.Power, Current = user.Type});
    }

    protected ICombinationAnalyzer(UsersProperties user, IReadOnlyList<int> hand) : base(user, hand)
    {

    }
}
```

`CardVariables` is just a class where I keep some variables used in the calculates down below. I don't think there's point in showing it here.

There are a few derived methods I'm not going to show entirely here because they are quite similar to one another.

```
public class RoyalFlush : ICombinationAnalyzer
{
    public RoyalFlush(UsersProperties user, IReadOnlyList<int> hand) : base(user, hand)
    {
    }

    public override void Check(int[] hand, UsersProperties user)
    {
        const int localType = (int) Hand.Combinations.RoyalFlush;
        foreach (
            var t in
                CombinedArrays.Where(t => t.Length >= 5)
                    .Where(
                        t =>
                            t[0] == (int) Cards.CardTypes.Ace && t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.Ten) &&
                            t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.Jack) && t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.Queen) &&
                            t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.King)))
        {
            UpdateHand(user, localType, t.Max()/4);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's one more:

```
public class Straight : ICombinationAnalyzer
{
    public Straight(UsersProperties user, IReadOnlyList<int> hand) : base(user, hand)
    {
    }

    public override void Check(int[] hand, UsersProperties user)
    {
        const int localType = (int) Hand.Combinations.Straight;
        int[] op = Straight.Select(o => o/4).Distinct().ToArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < op.Length - 4; j++)
        {
            if (op[j] + 1 == op[j + 1] && op[j] + 2 == op[j + 2] && op[j] + 3 == op[j + 3] && op[j] + 4 == op[j + 4])
            {
                UpdateHand(user, localType, op.Max() - 4 == op[j] ? op.Max() : op[j + 4]);
            }
            if (op[j] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Ace || op[j + 1] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Ten ||
                op[j + 2] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Jack || op[j + 3] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Queen ||
                op[j + 4] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.King) continue;

            UpdateHand(user, localType, 13);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is where I'm actually implementing the strategy pattern:

```
List<SwitchCombination> listCombinations = new List<SwitchCombination>();
                var switchCombination = new SwitchCombination( new HighCard(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new PairFromTable(user,_reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new PairInHand(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new PairHandTable(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairFromTable(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairHandPairTablePair(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairHandTable(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairTwoDifferent(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new ThreeOfAKind(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.Straight(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.Flush(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.FullHouse(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.FourOfAKind(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.StraightFlush(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.RoyalFlush(user, _reserve));
                listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
                foreach (var listCombination in listCombinations)
                {
                    listCombination.CheckCombination(user, _reserve);
                }
```

It's my first time ever doing this pattern and I'm not sure if it can be made any better but i know that if I'm writing something similar a couple times there's probably a better way of doing it. I created list of those Combinations so i can iterate through them this way I avoid typing 
`switchCombinations.CheckCombination(user, _reserve);` all the time.

However, I can't seem to find a way to reduce the overall size of that. As I said earlier, it's my first time implementing this pattern and I'm not sure if it's even effective or if that's the right way to go.

**EDIT :**  Added the `SwitchCombination` class :

```
    internal class SwitchCombination
{
    private readonly ICombinationAnalyzer _combinationAnalyzer;

    public SwitchCombination(ICombinationAnalyzer combination)
    {
        _combinationAnalyzer = combination;
    }

    public void CheckCombination(UsersProperties inputUser, int[] inputHand)
    {
        _combinationAnalyzer.Check(inputHand, inputUser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an `public abstract class` called `ICombinationAnalyzer`: that's wrong, only interfaces can use the `I` prefix. Instead I'd expect this class to have `Base` in its name at the start or the end (whatever is your preference).

---

This seems odd: `user.Power = powerType + user.Type*100;` To me it would make more sense for the user to have a `powerType` field, and for `Power` to simply be a `get` which returns `powerType + Type*100;`.

I'm confused by all of `UpdateHand(UsersProperties user, int combinationType, int powerType)`, to be honest: this method updates two properties of its parameter `user` and then calls `MainPoker.Win.Add(new Hand {Power = user.Power, Current = user.Type});` which doesn't look like it updates a `Hand`, but instead adds a new one.

Why are `combinationType` and `powerType` `int`s? Their names suggest they should be `enum`s, but then you use them in a calculation...

This whole method throws up all kinds of warning signs to me and I can't shake the feeling you have some fundamental flaws in the design of your solution.

---

The `RoyalFlush` also raises some questions: `Hand.Combinations.RoyalFlush` is cast to an `int` -- so why isn't it one in the first place? Same with `Cards.CardTypes.Ace` and others in that namespace.

Why the need for `Hand.Combinations.` and `Cards.CardTypes.` in the first place? It seems odd to use subclasses for such fundamental values.

This whole block is just a mess:

```
t[0] == (int) Cards.CardTypes.Ace 
&& t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.Ten) 
&& t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.Jack) 
&& t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.Queen) 
&& t.Contains((int) Cards.CardTypes.King)))
```

Even formatted like this I feel there's too much going on: the casts to `int` don't help, plus there's the odd check that the first item is an `Ace` while you use `.Contains()` for the other types.

---

But Straight is even worse than `RoyalFlush` and just is incomprehensible. What is `op`? Why do you need to execute `int[] op = Straight.Select(o => o/4).Distinct().ToArray();` each time -- it's not likely to change, now is it?

`op[j] + 1 == op[j + 1] && op[j] + 2 == op[j + 2] && op[j] + 3 == op[j + 3] && op[j] + 4 == op[j + 4]` suggests that `op` is sorted, but there's no evidence of this being the case.

This next bit looks a lot like a similar block in `RoyalFlush` above and I'm wondering whether they shouldn't be the same.

```
if (op[j] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Ace 
    || op[j + 1] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Ten 
    || op[j + 2] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Jack 
    || op[j + 3] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.Queen 
    || op[j + 4] != (int) Cards.CardTypes.King) 
{
    continue;
}
```

---

The "problem" you identify seems trivial. You can easily reduce it to this:

```
var listCombinations = new List<SwitchCombination>
{
    new SwitchCombination(new HighCard(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new PairFromTable(user,_reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new PairInHand(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new PairHandTable(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairFromTable(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairHandPairTablePair(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairHandTable(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new TwoPairTwoDifferent(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new ThreeOfAKind(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.Straight(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.Flush(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.FullHouse(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.FourOfAKind(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.StraightFlush(user, _reserve)),
    new SwitchCombination(new Combinations.RoyalFlush(user, _reserve)),
}
```

I'd probably refactor that even more, but right now you only posted fragments of your code and it's too much work to fill in the gaps.

---

UPDATE: The `SwitchCombination` you posted is a completely superfluous wrapper class, if that's all of its code. `var listCombinations = new List<SwitchCombination>` should instead be something like `var combinationAnalyzers = new List<BaseCombinationAnalyzer>` and be filled with classes that implement `BaseCombinationAnalyzer`, e.g. `new PairFromTable(user,_reserve)` instead of `new SwitchCombination(new PairFromTable(user,_reserve))`.

Comment: Once i have the powerType declared as a field `public int powerType;` should i just change powerType instead of changing the Power property will it automatically update the Power property ? Yes `UpdateHand(UsersProperties user, int combinationType, int powerType)` doesn't update's Hand it just adds one more to the `Win` which is a list, later on when the game is about to end i check every player if he has the highest Hand in Win, if he has it than he wins.I know there are problems with my naming .. `combinationType` indeed should be enum type im getting the value from enum anyway

Comment: "Hand.Combinations.RoyalFlush is cast to an int -- so why isn't it one in the first place?" Are you suggesting me to convert the `Hand.Combinations.RoyalFlush` enum to a static class ? The weird check has `t[0]` for no actual reason. If i switch it to contains too how can i improve it even more ? `Straight.Select(o => o/4).Distinct().ToArray();` WILL change everytime a new user is checking his hand the `Straight` arrays is being changed a little bit. `op[j] + 1 == op[j + 1]` and so on how can i make this one better should i use some LINQ ? I really dont know it will look so if you can do it..

Comment: "This next bit looks a lot like a similar block in RoyalFlush above and I'm wondering whether they shouldn't be the same." You are probably right about this.

Comment: Note that a field shouldn't be `public`, that would make it a property. WRT the rest of your comments: the code you posted is too fragmented to tell. I'd advise you to post a new question and post more complete code excerpts, perhaps including a link to a repository.

Comment: how should i declare it than ? `private int powerType; public int PowerType
        {
            get { return powerType; }
            set { powerType = value; }
        }` this looks like a property too

Comment: @denis It depends on whether you want the field to be exposed or not.

Comment: I really dont want to expose that much so i prefer it private

Answer (score 3):

One note on naming: `ICombinationAnalyzer` is a class—albeit abstract—not an interface, so its name should not start with `I`.

This boilerplate initialization code can be made much shorter and easier to read if you dispense with that local variable, which is doing nothing for you.

This:

```
List<SwitchCombination> listCombinations = new List<SwitchCombination>();
var switchCombination = new SwitchCombination( new HighCard(user, _reserve));
listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
switchCombination = new SwitchCombination(new PairFromTable(user,_reserve));
listCombinations.Add(switchCombination);
```

can become

```
List<SwitchCombination> listCombinations = new List<SwitchCombination>();
listCombinations.Add(new SwitchCombination(new HighCard(user, _reserve)));
listCombinations.Add(new SwitchCombination(new PairFromTable(user,_reserve));
```

Just as you say

> I created list of those Combinations so i can iterate through them
>   this way I avoid typing  switchCombinations.CheckCombination(user,
>   _reserve); all the time.

which is good thinking, you could also change to creating a list of `CombinationAnalyzer` objects and map over it to create the list of `SwitchCombination` objects that you need, rather than making all those `new SwitchCombination(…` constructor calls manually.

More generally, I wonder if you are really using Strategy. Without the code of `SwitchCombination` it is difficult to know. But the motivation of Strategy is to allow a choice at runtime of one possibility at a time out of several different implementations of an algorithm. If I understand what you are doing here seems more like the intention of the Chain of Command pattern.

The local variable `localType` in your implementations of the `Check` method isn't doing much for you, either. I suggest you inline it.